# Run a dev server in CI pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a CI pipeline setup using Github Action/Workflows, where I want to run Cypress Automated tests; however I am having some problems of when trying to run my dev server. Let me show you my pipeline:

```
name: Nuxt CI Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches: [ CI-pipeline ]
  # pull_request:
  #   branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [ 14.x ]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - name: Make envfile
      uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1
      with:
        envkey_ENV: staging
        file_name: .env
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run dev
    - run: | 
        cd e2e
        ls -l
        npm ci
        npx cypress run
```

Now I want to spin up the devserver and run the tests on that port usually 3000; however the problem is when the command `npm run dev` is executed, the pipeline keeps on waiting there and doesn't move forward to the next commands, which makes sense as devserver doesn't return a response – it listens on that port until explicitly closed. I'm stuck here. My knowledge of devops is the bare minimum; can someone point out what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline is configured correctly, you were just missing one piece of the puzzle called [service containers](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers).

Basically, the service containers also known as sidecars will run alongside your "main" pipeline logic and support your commands. In your case, you will run the `npm run dev` in a service container once the build job starts and when the `npx cypress run` runs it will have a dev server to connect to.

Follow the example GitHub added for [Redis](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/creating-redis-service-containers)